Practical Implementation of A Two Quadrant Transconductance Analogue Multiplier
Currently cannot simulate a functional Two Quadrant Transconductance Analogue Multiplier.
Understood constraints:
Vx is small (Vx << Vt ~ 25mV)
Vy is greater than VBE(on)(0.6V) (a DC offset would be needed).
For this Cicuit (a) I understand the Vo = VxVy(RL / (RE*Vt)) where RL -> R1/R2 and RE -> RE in the text book example.
Ultimately I want to create an Vo eq. to Vo = KVx^2 + B where K,B are some constant value to correct to obtain Vo = V^2.
Theoretically
RL = 1000;
RE  = 100;
Vt = 25*10^-3;
Vx = 0.0002;
Vy = 1+0.0002;
Should me Vo = 0.000016 V however under simulation in LTSpice I cannot recreate a theoretical value to pass to a differential amplifier usually orders of magnitude out. For those who may suggest using an existing IC to perform this calculation that is not what I am trying to achieve, I want to recreate a textbook example in LTSpice to then bench test for educational purposes. I have Tried Messing round with R values with no success the values imaged was just a random last ditch edit to get it working. Can someone please correct this and explain how to get a result which matches a given eq.




Please ask a more specific question of where you are stuck.

Connecting Q10's base to Vx is not going to work. It must be connected to Vy.
Additionally, the emitter resistor of Q10 must be connected to a significantly lower voltage than the base of the differential pair transistors (connecting it to ground won't work). Connect something like -5V there and adjust Vy to be relative to this negative voltage.
This is shown in sub-figure (b) of your textbook as the "-VEE" connection.

I've added another photo to address your comment, even when having the two different inputs the circuit does not work. In the orignal it was a photo of the attempt at that moment which I tried Vy = Vx to see what happened. Here you can also see that when Vy = Vx + 1 and Vx = 0.00002 The circuit does not work.

@CXX_NVCC Sorry, I missed the actual problem. I've corrected the answer.

I changed the GND to VEE at the bottom of the circuit with the following values inputted
RL = 1000;
RE  = 100;
Vt = 25*10^-3;
Vx = 0.00002;
Vo = Vx (Vx + 1) (RL/(RE * Vt))
Expected 0.00800016 got 4.776216 - 4.4766331 = 0.299583 which is not an expected result? *Note VCC -> 5V and VEE -> -5V

@CXX_NVCC Where are you getting the "Vx + 1" from? Q10's Vbe is lower than 1V, so it's correct that you're getting a greater output voltage than 0.008V. The circuit works, you just need to make Vy lower. You can also replace Q10 with a current sink to get more accurate bias current.

I'm getting "Vx+1" from the fact that Vy is greater than VBE(on)(0.6V) (a DC offset would be needed). Here I'm using Vy = "Vx+1" where 1 is my DC offset. If I drop Vy to "Vx+0.6" I get a predicted 0.00480016 with an actual Vo being 0.001632. With regards to "You can also replace Q10 with a current sink to get more accurate bias current." I'm not sure exactly what this means with regards to the circuit diagram. What current sink would I implement, and is Q10 not currently Sinking current to VEE?

@CXX_NVCC Q10 is sinking current, but the amount of current it sinks is very inaccurate due to its poorly defined Vbe. You need a better current sinking circuit, i.e. an OpAmp-based one.
